# Get a certain string before the specified string and after the second specified string [BATCH]

Tags: json, for-loop, batch-file, find

I'm making a Batch script to get the actual stock of an product on a page,
The JSON is :

```
... ,"src":"https://www.datocms-assets.com/34299/1615563408-h510-elite-white-black-fan-bracket-out.png?ar64=MTox&auto=format&fit=crop&h=375&w=375","width":375,"height":375,"alt":null,"title":null}}],"aliasImage":null,"price":179.99,"stock":0,"id":260,"shopify_variants_id":39412773781641,"shopify_parent_id":6596349198473,"isValid":true,"isLowStock":true,"isOutOfStock":true,"discounted_price":124.99,"isOnSale":true,"isComingSoon":false,"isNewItem":false,"showSaleTag":false,"isPromo":true,"showCountdownTimer":false,"countdownEndDate":null,"showPercentOff":true,"percentOff":30,"showInventoryCount":false,"showAmountOff":false,"amountOff":0,"isBestSeller":false} ...
```

I need to get the stock, the  and the dismounted price, if someone would be able to help me make this, i would appreciate it.
I precise that they are multiples : "discounted_price" and "price" on the json, it contains all the nzxt product

i've thinked about getting the string before : "id":260 but found nothing working correctly.
i dont need exactly this idea, but i need: something that work! thanks you ^^

Comment: To begin with, that is only a snippet from the JSON, not its entire content. In addition it would help if you told us the type of line endings the file was using, (CrLf, Lf, Cr), and if that is really all on one line. It would also help if we had the file encoding, (ANSI, Unicode), and if you told us why you're wanting a batch file to parse JSON, when PowerShell has built in JSON functionality, and batch files don't. Additionally this site does not offer a free code writing service, we expect you to write your own code, and we try to help you where you're stuck, or if it fails.

Comment: Hi, i'm really bad at powershell, i dont know any command of it, secondly the encoding is ansi and i need this script to be warned when the h510 elite case is available to purchase on the website nzxt.com.

Comment: Well based upon your question content, you we have no idea how 'bad' or 'good' you may be with batch files either. We expect your code, and as I already implied, just a small portion of your JSON is not good enough, (as can be noted in your [subsequent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74534329/get-a-certain-string-before-the-specified-string-and-after-the-second-specified?noredirect=1#comment131571986_74535339)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This is not a code-writting service. You should write your own code and we give help with it.
- A Batch file is *not* the right tool to process JSON data.
- We need an *actual* data in order to do tests on it.

Anyway, this is a small Batch code that *may* help:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set json={"src":"https://www.datocms-assets.com/34299/1615563408-h510-elite-white-black-fan-bracket-out.png?ar64=MTox&auto=format&fit=crop&h=375&w=375","width":375,"height":375,"alt":null,"title":null}}],"aliasImage":null,"price":179.99,"stock":0,"id":260,"shopify_variants_id":39412773781641,"shopify_parent_id":6596349198473,"isValid":true,"isLowStock":true,"isOutOfStock":true,"discounted_price":124.99,"isOnSale":true,"isComingSoon":false,"isNewItem":false,"showSaleTag":false,"isPromo":true,"showCountdownTimer":false,"countdownEndDate":null,"showPercentOff":true,"percentOff":30,"showInventoryCount":false,"showAmountOff":false,"amountOff":0,"isBestSeller":false}

rem Remove from beginning up to "width"
set "json=%json:*width="width%"

rem Change quote-colon by equal-sign
set "json=%json:":==%"

rem Separate comma-delimited parts and assign them to individual variables
set %json:,=" & set %

echo stock=%stock%
echo discounted_price=%discounted_price%
```

The output of this code is:

```
stock=0
discounted_price=124.99
```

Please, do *not* post a comment indicating that this code does *not* work with your actual data! **`:(`** Instead, remove the `@echo off` line, run the program, comprehend how it works and insert the needed modifications until the program correctly work...

Comment: Hi, in theory your code is right, but i putted only a little part of the json, and now that the json is just huge, i'm getting so many error like : 'h' is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program or a command file.

Comment: this is the json link : https://nzxt.com/_next/data/J3uug-4aYtZgtifEiv-9p/fr-FR/product/h510-elite.json

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1040280006452072559/1044641799035174943/image.png

Comment: Its caused by the & char as i see

Comment: It is good that you have the actual data!  You need to think in these points now: 1- How do you think to _read_ such a huge line in a Batch file? Write a simple Batch file that just _read_ the Json data...  2- How do you want to identify the right stock data? There are 17 stocks in such a Json file... Good look! **`;)`**

Comment: My problem actually is to import the json, i'm making a curl to download the page but i want to import it, so i made set /p json=<json.json but its only giving me a part of the file, from {"pageProps":{ to "content":"https://nzxt.c

Comment: Well, your question title and the problem description specified that your problem was just extract the desired data... With such an information we assumed that the data could be read by a Batch file.

Comment: do you think you are able to help me in powershell to do it ? i really need a automated script to know when the case is online for christmas